# Why pvbatch freezes when running a forloop around source fileNames

Tags: python, paraview

I am using pvbatch to generate screenshot out of a series of cgns files. The process works well, only sometime pvbatch freezes (it does not crash, it just stop progressing...)

Under linux (using Paraview 5.3.0) I am calling:
pvbatch --mesa-llvm --use-offscreen-rendering make_all_videos_trunk.py

And my python code looks like this:

```
from paraview.simple import *
import os


def get_cgns_source():
    _sources = GetSources()
    _cgnsKeys = []
    for _k in _sources.keys():
        if "CGNSSeriesReader" in _sources[_k].__repr__():
            _cgnsKeys.append(_k)

    if len(_cgnsKeys) == 1:
        return _sources[_cgnsKeys[0]]
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not find the CGNS source")

def reset_session():
    pxm = servermanager.ProxyManager()
    pxm.UnRegisterProxies()
    del pxm
    Disconnect()
    Connect()

gridName = "Grid5a_1.1m"
stateSource = r"video3_template.pvsm"
mainPath = os.path.join(os.curdir,gridName)
pathFigures = os.path.join(mainPath, "_summary", "_figures")

if not os.path.exists(pathFigures):
    os.mkdir(pathFigures)

# go through all cases under that grid
for caseName in os.listdir(mainPath):
    casePath = os.path.join(mainPath, caseName)

    reset_session()
    LoadState(stateSource)
    cgnsReader = get_cgns_source()

    _stepsRange = []
    for fileName in os.listdir(casePath):
        if fileName.startswith('out-') and fileName.endswith("solution.cgns"):    
            _stepsRange.append(int(fileName.replace("_solution.cgns","").replace('out-','')))

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathFigures,caseName)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(pathFigures,caseName))

    for iStep in _stepsRange:
        _sStep = str(iStep).zfill(8)
        filePath = os.path.join(casePath, "out-%s_solution.cgns" % _sStep)
        cgnsReader.FileNames = filePath
        figName = 'Fig_%s.png' % _sStep
        print figName
        _figPathTemp = os.path.join(pathFigures,caseName, figName)
        SaveScreenshot(_figPathTemp, layout=GetLayout())
```

Did I miss something on the "cleaning" side ? Something else ?

Thanks for the help!